# replacing one word in one line in a file

Tags: unix, sed

I understand I can use sed to replace a word in a file with a different word. but what if I have a word that might appear several times in a file and I only want to change it in a specific line, in the end of it. 
lets say I have

```
hello unix world olga unix olga unix 
hello unix 2013 world
```

assuming I know the number of the line, how do I replace the second "unix" in the first line and leave others unchanged?
all expressions as well as the line number are saved in variables

Comment: In your comments below, you're adding additional criteria which you haven't mentioned in your question.  Please update your question to include any additional criteria as well as code you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you(GNU sed):

```
sed '1s/unix/whatever/2' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is on the 1st line, you can use:

```
sed '1s/unix/windows/' < input.txt
```

If however you want to replace the *first* occurence of *unix*, then the task is a bit more involved. In theory, `sed` allows specifying the match number as:

```
sed 's/unix/windows/1' < input.txt
```

However it is non-portable and can hardly be relied upon. It might be easier to either use a more specific pattern (assuming such a line indeed has a unique pattern) or using `awk` or some other scripting language.

Comment: lets assume I know which line it is. what if I have "unix" twice or more in the same line and I only want to replace the last one (the word I want to change will definitely appear in the very end of the line)

Comment: can I use '1s/&unix$/windows/' if the word I need is saved in a variable named unix?

Comment: Yes, you can, as long as you _construct_ your command string properly. Assuming your line number and word to replace are in variables `line` and `word` respectively, use: `"${line}s/${word}/windows/"`. Note that it would only work to a point, e.g. your line should be a number and your word should not have characters `sed` might consider control ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand your search pattern to only include what you're looking for.

In your case, you could look for

```
sed 's/unix$/windows/'
```

Which says, search for `unix` at the end of a line `$` and replace it with `windows`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '1s/unix$/windows/' file
```

it does substitution only on first line, and only for the last word, if it was `unix`.

if you want to do in-place replacement, use `sed -i 's/...' file`

Comment: what if the word I look for saved in a variable named unix. will $unix$ work for changing the word in the end of the line?

Comment: @littlerunaway then you need `sed "s/$unix$/foo/"` note, double quotes are important.

Comment: and if the line number is also a variable?

Comment: @littlerunaway why not just put those info in your question? anyway, if both ln and pattern are var, you could: `sed "$lnr s/$unix$/foo/"`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the word "unix" with "windows" on line 1 if "unix" appears at the end of the line:

```
sed 's1/unix$/windows/' input_file > output_file
```

s1 constrains the match to line 1

$ constrains the match to the end of the line